# Time Manager animations run too fast to simulate real time

Tags: qgis-3, qgis-plugins, animation, time-series, timemanager

I am using the Time Manager plugin to visualize a set of points with a corresponding start and end time. I can see the points correctly on the map at the correct time. My question is about the visualization options as I want to continuously see what happens every second to simulate real time. I set "time frame size" to "1 second" and on "Settings" I set "Show frame for 1000 milliseconds". However, the time is running faster than 1 second and I don't understand why.

QGIS version is 3.12. and the points in my list have the coordinates and start and end time as the following example.

```
35.74849    -9.16069    2018-01-01 00:20:00     2018-01-01 21:53:00
```